# Hibernate Help required

Tags: hibernate

I tried to look around for information regarding returning a list using Hibnerate but couldn't find something that matches what I'm looking for and thus needs some advise.

I have the following classes

**BPDataPK:**

```
  public class BPDataPK implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private int userProfile;
    private Date when;      
         .....
  }
```

**BPData:**

```
public class BPData implements Serializable {   
   private BPDataPK dataPK;
   private Date sessionStart;
    ...
}
```

**HibernateBPDataDAO :**

```
public class HibernateBPDataDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport implements IBPDataDAO{
    ....
public BPData[] getSessionBPData(Session session) throws Exception {
        /**I need to get a list of BPData that matches the following
        1.  BPDataPK.id== session.getID;
        2.  BPDataPK.userProfile == session.getUserProfile;
        **3.  BPData.sessionStart  == session.getSessionStart();**
        */
    }
 }
```

How do I return a list of BPData that matches two of the primary key and a non primary key??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not *look around* for some information. Instead, you should read the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/).

This documentation has a full chapter dedicated to queries using the HQL query language, and another one dedicated to criteria queries. Since you have a fixed set of criteria here, HQL is more suited to the task:

```
String hql = "select b from BPData b where b.dataPK.id = :id"
             + " and b.dataPK.userProfile = :profile"
             + " and b.sessionStart = :sessionStart";
Query q = hibernateSession.createQuery(hql);
q.setString("id", session.getID());
q.setInt("profile", session.getUserProfile());
q.setTimestamp("sessionStart", session.getSessionStart()); // or setDate, depending on the type of this field
List<BPData> result = q.list();
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.
However I'm getting a Unexpected token [b] [select b from ....]
I also visited the reference you given, they are also using the similar pattern as your syntax.

Comment: I forgot the b alias. My answer is fixed. If you had read the documentation, you could have found it by yourself.

Comment: Once again thanks for your help.
I didn't notice that difference. :$
I have simplify the HQL to just check for the sessionStart, but the hibnerate is not returning any data.
in the MYSQL database, the content is (datetime data type) 2011-04-29 11:43:00
tried with q.setTimestamp("sessionStart", session.getSessionStart());
and q.setDate("sessionStart", session.getSessionStart()); without success.
getSessionStart return a java.util.Date;

Answer (score 1):

if you are using JPA immplementaion of hibernate you do this

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(
    name="findByMyQuery",
    queryString="SELECT bpdata FROM BPData bpdata WHERE bpdata.dataPK = :sessionId AND bpdata.userProfile = :userProfile AND bpdata.sessionStart = :sessionStart "
)
public class BPData implements Serializable {

    private BPDataPK dataPK;
    private Date sessionStart;
        ...
    }


public BPData[] getSessionBPData(Session session) throws Exception {       

    Query queryFindByMyQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findByMyQuery");
    queryEmployeeByFirstName.setParameter("sessionId", session.getID());
    queryEmployeeByFirstName.setParameter("userProfile", session.getUserProfile());
    queryEmployeeByFirstName.setParameter("sessionStart", session.getSessionStart());
    return queryEmployessByFirstName.getResultList().toArray();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply too, however I'm very new to Hibernate, I not really sure whether I'm using the JPA. however for my saving and update, I using the getHibernateTemplate().save();